# Firebase transaction getChildrenCount() "cached"?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use a firebase transaction and I need to get the number of children in my node. Here is my code :

```
mynoderef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("mynode");
                    mynoderef.keepSynced(true);

                mynoderef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                    @Override
                    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                        Log.d("fumee", "fumee5 = " + mutableData.getChildrenCount());

                        for (final MutableData postSnapshot : mutableData.getChildren()) {...
```

My issue is that I can see in my log that the number I get from `mutableData.getChildrenCount()` is not always correct. 
It seems to come from cache because when it is wrong it gives me the number from the previous "load". I guess my issue is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170187/firebase-getchildrencount-is-counting-deleted-data).

`setPersistenceEnabled` is true in my app and I want to keep it. 
Do you see how to resolve my issue?

Thank you,

Alex

Comment: Also interested in this. Any solution, 10 months later?